# Grand total is wrong: VAT is substracted

Tags: magento-1.9, vat, magento-1.9.2.0

We've recently upgraded from Magento **v1.7.2** to **v1.9.2** using *Magento Connect Manager*.
At first we were very happy it went rather smootly.

But now we noticed the grand total price is completely wrong.
All my prices are including VAT. I have one product in my cart which costs € 5.85
My cart overview is:

```
Subtotal:                 € 5.85
Total (excl. VAT)         € 3.81
VAT                       € 1.02
Grand Total (incl. VAT)   € 4.83
```

The subtotal is OK, the VAT is wrong. It should be 21% which is 1.23 and the grand total should stay 5.85. Now my customers are paying less than they should be. It looks like some settings have been set to different values after upgrading, but I can't figure out which setting I need to change.

Does anybody have a link to some documentation about how to set the VAT in Magento **CE v1.9.2**? I could find some for older version but they didn't help.

**Update**
As requested here is a screenshot of my tax settings. It is in Dutch however:
[image: My tax settings]

Comment: It's very unlikely that anything has changed. Here's whole change log if you want to be sure: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.html

Do you have any 3rd party extension that's related to  Catalog/Tax/Discount/Cart/Checkout? Please paste a screenshot of your tax configuration from Configuration > Sales > Tax

Comment: Can we also see the VAT rules and classes? Did you reindex after upgrading?