# Magento 1.8.0.1 - Grand total is showing subtracted VAT

Tags: magento-1.8, totals, grand-total

Having the exact same problem as here [Grand total is wrong: VAT is substracted](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76268/grand-total-is-wrong-vat-is-substracted)
But there is not answer to the question, so im trying again, and hope someone can help.

As you can see on the picture, there is a problem with grand total, but subtotal is showing correct, anyone that can think of something that could be wrong here?
I have tried everything in the VAT backend VAT settings for cart.

[image]

Comment: Is there any shopping cart price rules applied ?

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered the same issue, steps to solve it are:

1. Go to this location: `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`
2. Make a copy of it in `app/code/local`: `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`
3. Next on line number 1221 add `msrp`:

   ```
   <shipping>
      <class>sales/quote_address_total_shipping</class>
      <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,msrp</after>
      <before>grand_total</before>
   </shipping>
   ```
4. Next add on line 1230 add:

   ```
   <msrp>
      <class>sales/quote_address_total_msrp</class>
      <before>grand_total</before>
   </msrp>
   ```
5. This should solve your issue. Thank you :)

Comment: Don't ask me why, but this works. Although make sure to fix it in your own separate module instead of directly editing the core.